# Getting CMake warning because of CMP0048 even after bumping up CMake Minimum Version

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Working on building and testing my ROS package in `noetic`. I get the following warning:

```
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
  contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
  code such as

    project(ProjectName)

  near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().

  CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
  line.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I have edited my CMakeLists.txt to have the following line to bump up minimum version of CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
```

Similar to [this](https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/1052).

But I am still getting the warning. Am I missing something? I am not seeing this in my `melodic` build.

Edit: My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(rosrect-listener-agent)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  roslib
  rosgraph_msgs
  std_msgs
)
set(cpprestsdk_DIR /usr/lib/${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE}/cmake/)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(cpprestsdk REQUIRED)

add_library(rosrect-listener-agent-lib src/backend_api.cpp src/robot_event.cpp src/state_manager.cpp)
target_link_libraries(rosrect-listener-agent-lib ${catkin_LIBRARIES} cpprestsdk::cpprest)
add_executable(rosrect-listener-agent src/listener_agent.cpp )
target_link_libraries(rosrect-listener-agent
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  rosrect-listener-agent-lib
  cpprestsdk::cpprest
)
add_dependencies(rosrect-listener-agent ${rosrect-listener-agent_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

#############
## Testing ##
#############
if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING AND ENABLE_COVERAGE_TESTING)
  find_package(code_coverage REQUIRED)
  # Add compiler flags for coverage instrumentation before defining any targets
  APPEND_COVERAGE_COMPILER_FLAGS()
endif()
if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  find_package(rostest REQUIRED)
  
  # Unit tests for utility classes as just gtest
  catkin_add_gtest(backend_test_node test/utests_backendapi.cpp)
  catkin_add_gtest(robotevent_test_node test/utests_robotevent.cpp)
  catkin_add_gtest(statemanager_test_node test/utests_statemanager.cpp)

  # Integration test for listener agent node as rostest
  add_rostest_gtest(listeneragent_test_node_ros test/listener_integration_test_ros.test test/itest_listeneragent_ros.cpp)
  add_rostest_gtest(listeneragent_test_node_db test/listener_integration_test_db.test test/itest_listeneragent_db.cpp)

  target_link_libraries(backend_test_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} rosrect-listener-agent-lib cpprestsdk::cpprest)
  target_link_libraries(robotevent_test_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} rosrect-listener-agent-lib cpprestsdk::cpprest)
  target_link_libraries(statemanager_test_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} rosrect-listener-agent-lib cpprestsdk::cpprest)
  target_link_libraries(listeneragent_test_node_ros ${catkin_LIBRARIES} rosrect-listener-agent-lib cpprestsdk::cpprest)
  target_link_libraries(listeneragent_test_node_db ${catkin_LIBRARIES} rosrect-listener-agent-lib cpprestsdk::cpprest)

  if(ENABLE_COVERAGE_TESTING)
    set(COVERAGE_EXCLUDES "*/${PROJECT_NAME}/test*" "*/${PROJECT_NAME}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}/*.h")
    add_code_coverage(
      NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}_coverage_report
      # DEPENDENCIES tests
    )
  endif()
endif()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357065/getting-cmake-warning-because-of-cmp0048-even-after-bumping-up-cmake-minimum-version/) by [swaroophs](https://answers.ros.org/users/53852/swaroophs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The shown warning has nothing to do with [CMP0048](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/policy/CMP0048.html).

It would be helpful if you would either share the content of your `CMakeLists.txt` as part of the question or reference the file in a public repository.

The warning literally mentions what the problem in the `CMakeLists.txt` (of your package) is and how you should be able to resolve it:

> No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of code such as
>
> ```
> project(ProjectName)
> ```
>
> near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().

**Update:**

The warning is being generated from to the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file when using `catkin_make` with CMake 3.15 or newer.

You can either:

- use `catkin_make_isolated` instead of `catkin_make` (which doesn't use a top-level CMake file,
- apply the patch from https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/1106 locally to the file `/opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake` manually, or
- wait for a new version of `catkin` to be released with the referenced patch.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [swaroophs](https://answers.ros.org/users/53852/swaroophs/) on 2020-07-13**:
Thanks @Dirk. I have pasted the contents of my CMakeLists.txt file above. I do have the project specified right below cmake_minimum_required.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-07-13**:
How are you invoking the build? I assume you use `catkin_make` - see updated answer.

**Comment by [swaroophs](https://answers.ros.org/users/53852/swaroophs/) on 2020-07-14**:
Thanks @Dirk. I am just using `catkin_make`. I tried the patch of just adding `project(Project)` to the top-level CMake and the warning has disappeared now.

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2020-09-04**:
I have the same warning triggered on the buildfarm using `catkin_make_isolated`, see here: http://build.ros.org/job/Ndev__ixblue_ins_stdbin_driver__ubuntu_focal_amd64/1/consoleFull at `18:09:34`

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-09-04**:
@rreignier Your error message is different from the one described in this question. Please ask a separate question and copy-n-paste the full error message instead of just referencing a build.